# Xcode clang fails with undefined symbol _zgeev_

Tags: c++, xcode, armadillo

I just updated an XCode project from macOS 10.14 to 11.0. Unfortunately, I forgot I also needed to run it on another 10.14 machine, so I went back to change the settings to compile for 10.14, but now it routinely fails with

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_zgeev_", referenced from:
      void arma::lapack::cx_geev<std::__1::complex<double> >(char*, char*, int*, std::__1::complex<double>*, int*, std::__1::complex<double>*, std::__1::complex<double>*, int*, std::__1::complex<double>*, int*, std::__1::complex<double>*, int*, std::__1::complex<double>::value_type*, int*) in EigenArmaGeneralizedEigenValues.o
  "_zggev_", referenced from:
      void arma::lapack::cx_ggev<std::__1::complex<double> >(char*, char*, int*, std::__1::complex<double>*, int*, std::__1::complex<double>*, int*, std::__1::complex<double>*, std::__1::complex<double>*, std::__1::complex<double>*, int*, std::__1::complex<double>*, int*, std::__1::complex<double>*, int*, std::__1::complex<double>::value_type*, int*) in EigenArmaGeneralizedEigenValues.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It looks like these are being drawn from my C++ lin alg library, Armadillo (arma) -- though I'm using the version I compiled for 10.14, so I'm not sure what the issue is. The only thing that has changed is my XCode project itself, all other files are the same.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you not use a version control system?

Comment: Lesson learned :)